# How to exit from .emacs init file?

Tags: init-file, exit

I want to debug my init file, by exiting from loading the file in the middle so if something is wrong after that place it will not be loaded. How can I exit from .emacs file?

Comment: Emacs will exit from your init file immediately once it finds something is wrong, so if you put `(1 + 1)` to the beginning of your init file, the rest will not be loaded at all. is this what you want? BTW, I don't think this method will help you to debug your init file at all.

Comment: @xuchunyang that help, but I think I used a function that was exiting from the emacs file some time ago when I was debugging init file but I don't remember what function it was.

Comment: You'd be better served by `--debug-init` option you can add when starting Emacs.

Comment: @wvxvw I always have that enabled.

Answer (score 9):

You can use this to exit from your init file:

```el
(with-current-buffer " *load*"
  (goto-char (point-max)))
```

Emacs uses the `load` function to execute lisp file through a temporary buffer, that's `" *load*"`, if the name is not already taken. The above code moves the point to the end of the buffer, thus the `read` function will not read further code.

For example, the last sexp of `foo.el` is unbalanced, but there is no error when running it, since Emacs can't go that far, it exits early:

```
~$ cat foo.el 
(message "Loading %s..." load-file-name)

(with-current-buffer " *load*"
  (goto-char (point-max)))

(this line does not matter
~$ emacs --batch --load foo.el
Loading /home/xcy/foo.el...
~$
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. why you have space in the begining of the name of the buffer is it a typo?

Comment: @jcubic No, it isn't. Buffer name starting with a space has a special meaning (see https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-Names.html if you are interested).

Comment: It seems like emacs should have a simple `(exit-load)` or `(return)` for this. What if the file is byte-compiled?

Comment: @NetMage When loading a byte-compiled file, I get `(error "no buffer named  *load*")`. See https://pastebin.com/yQ3PDdJr.

Comment: For compilation the equivalent buffer would be `" *Compiler Input*"`.